# Copy constructor calling copy constructor of another class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I was wondering, can I and if I do, how to call a copy constructor of template class `A` in copy constructor of class `B`, both class are not in the same file.

```
template<typename T> class A: public AP<T>
{
    public:
        A();
        A(const A&);
        ~A();
};



#include "A"
class B: public BP
{
    private:
       A<int> Amember;
    public:
        B();
        B(const B&);
        ~B();
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Need more information -- what are you trying to copy?  Does `B` have an `A` type member?  Is the `BP` type somehow related to `AP`?

Comment: "both inherit of a class AP and BP" - from what we see, they don't. One inherits from `AP` and the other from `BP`. Anyhow, `B` doesn't have/isn't `A`.

Comment: Oh yes sorry LogicStuff I don't express myself properly, i'm going to add you some inofs

Comment: You cannot have `A<T> Amember;` in `B`, since it's not a class template (having `T` as parameter). Either make it one or specify the `T` - `A<int> Amember;`.

Comment: Yeah actually it was already the case, sorry I was mistaken when I made the example :s

Comment: Or `B(const B&) = default;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys it's working :)

Comment: Consider following the *Rule of Zero* for class design, in which case you do not need to write a copy constructor or a destructor

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think you're after the optional initializer list in the constructor of your B class. Doesn't matter if you want to call the default constructor or copy constructor. In the definition of the constructor, you can put a colon and the list of how each member variable should be initialized. i.e., which constructor should be called.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
  public:
   A(){cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;}
   A(int i){cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<" "<<i<<endl; data = i;}
   A(const A& a){cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl; data = a.data;}
  private:
   int data;
};

class B{
  public:
   B() : a(){}
   B(int i) : a(i){}
   B(const B& b) : a(b.a) {}
  private:
   A a;
};

int main(){
  B b1; // default constructor

  B b2(5); // integer constructor

  B b3(b2); // copy constructor

}
```